# How to scroll up and down in sliced "screen" terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, gnu-screen

I just installed `screen` and like the idea to divide linux terminal into multiple pieces. But I can't figure out one thing: How to scroll up and down, when I'm in `screen`. When I'm using regular linux terminal I can achieve this with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>`. but unfortunatelly it doesn't work in divided terminal.

That's what I mean when saying `screen` and divided terminal:
[image]

And that's a regular termina (just in case):
[image]

Answer (score 329, accepted):

1.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> 
2. After that, you should be able to move your cursor around using the arrow keys:
<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and sometimes using the mouse wheel

3. Return control: <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Why can't I just use the navigation keys like I normally would?

Comment: @MihaiDanila: How would you "normally" use the navigation keys? The navigation keys are handled by the current foreground application. If it's an editor, they'll probably work.  If it's a shell, they'll probably go back through your command history without scrolling the display.

Comment: If my pageup/pagedown keys work in a normal shell, I'd like for them to work in a shell from `screen`. I think that's what I'm asking here.

Comment: However if its in [control+a -> escape] mode you will not get any update on the screen till you exit this mode(using escape).

Comment: in this mode selection of any text is available by typing **Space** or **Enter** key once and finish your text selection with another **Space** or **Enter**. the selection will enter into the screen based clipboard. you could paste clipboard data later using **Ctrl+a** then **]**

Comment: for all new folks coming here, @Eduardo answer works. See below. I tried on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can than also use the **page up** & **page down** keys (iso arrow keys)

Comment: It is working, but it have limited scroll back buffer, I cannot scroll up more than two pages. Using screen to serial on mac.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @MihaiDanila welcome to 1972

Answer (score 43):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>[</kbd> will enter the copy mode, and you can scroll up and down like *vim* editor.
Leave the copy mode by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Comment: This answer also works when you are using Git Bash to log in a server.

Answer (score 33):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Escape</kbd> to enter in "*Copy mode*". After that, you should be able to move your cursor around using the arrow keys. To exit, press <kbd>Escape</kbd> again.

Another way is to do the following to use *Mouse Scrollwheel*:

```
echo 'termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@' >> ~/.screenrc
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I need a screen session on the bastion host because of my sometimes flaky connection, but I absolutely need to have the option to scrollback with the terminal emulator software itself instead of screen, either huge chunks of output or line by line. I knew about the `CTRL + A` stuff, but that doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: methinks this should be the answer. It works well with standard configs under screen + ubuntu 16.04 + putty

Comment: This doesn't actually work if you switch screens. It feels like it works, but when you scroll back you quickly get garbage from other screens.

Comment: @Trevor maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it works fine for me?

Comment: @toast Is your screen session remote over SSH? That's the situation I am in and that might be why it works for you and not for me.

Comment: @Trevor Yeah, remote over SSH. I'm on a mac using iterm2 in case that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> (default prefix) + <kbd>[</kbd>: Enter copy mode.

<kbd>Esc</kbd>: Quit copy mode.

Within copy mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>: Page up/down by certain amount of lines while preserving cursor position (default by half of the screen)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>: Page up/down by a full screen

Comment: ctrl-b paged up for me still - ctrl+f was the page down

Answer (score 4):

Scrolling works in screen with 'terminator' in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Comment: Terminator is really good when you can use X11. Otherwise look at another solutions.